# to get a hired knife vs to get hired

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, collocations

I was reading the comic book Batman The Long Haloween and I came across a question involving the verb ''to get'' in the following excerpt: ''It seems like only yesterday when The Roman tried to get a hiered knife slid between his nephew's ribs''.

What is the meaning of the verb "to get" in this sentence? The writer was just being sarcastic with the idea that The Roman "tried to stick a rented knife" between his nephew's ribs or there wasn't any kind of sarcasm regarding the verb "to get" and in this case "to get a rented knife" does it mean that he hired someone (in the literal sense) to threaten his nephew with a knife? would it be the same thing as ''to get hired''?

Comment: If a knife is being slid between your ribs, you aren't being 'threatened', you're being killed.

Comment: "Hired knife" isn't a common usage, but it's easily understood by analogy to ***hired gun*** from the days of the Wild West ("hired gun" = ***gunman for hire***).

Comment: Thank you all. I'm going to put the entire text so you can see the full context of this part of the story.
''Carmine 'The Roman' Falconi, Gotham City's untouchable Crime Lord is throwing a society wedding for his nephew Jonny Viti. It seems like only yestardy when The Roman tried to get a hired knife slid between his nephew's ribs.
 Jonny was going to tell everything he knew about The Roman to The Grand Jury. Extortion. Corruption. Murder.  All of it.
 But, Jonny never testified. He's getting married instead. With The Roman paying for it. All of it''.

Comment: The "to get" is like the "to get" in "to get a haircut", it means to organise, cause, incite, order or pay for something to be done, that something in this case being "a hired knife slid between his nephew's ribs."  A hired knife could be either the knife wielded by a hired killer or the hired killer wielding that knife. In this case it's the former.

Comment: I have to say, I was confused by references to "hired knives" and "rented knives", especially when "slid between the ribs". It simply sounds like poor writing.

Comment: Yeah. You know, Batman The Long Halloween is considered one of the best Batman stories. The writer could have put a little more effort to avoid ''taking a dump'' like that in the script.

Answer (score 0):

To "get something done" means to cause that thing to happen. So, you're correct, if he tried to "get a hired knife slid between his nephew's ribs," it sounds like he tried to cause a "hired knife" - i.e., a knife held by someone he hired - to be slid between his nephew's ribs.

To answer your other point - to "get [adjective/past participle]" would be a slightly different grammatical structure. It means, simply, to become [adjective], so to "get hired" would mean to become hired - i.e., to be hired by someone.

A side point. I don't love the writing here. A "hired knife" sounds to me like it should refer to a person - i.e., a gangster that uses a knife. A "hired gun" is sometimes used this way. Instead, the author is referring to the weapon itself as the "hired knife."

Comment: I wouldn't be a fan of the prose either, but the use of "hired knife" is an interesting case of a writer turning an already pretty established metaphor back in on itself. It's a bit involved, but it does seem consistent with the sort of thing a fella in a fedora might say while chewing a matchstick.

Answer (score 0):

A "hired knife" is akin to a ["hired gun"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hired%20gun), it does not refer to a literal weapon, but rather the person who uses it, i.e. a mercenary engaged in illicit work, in this case an assassin. The writer is being metaphorical by referring to the hired killer by his weapon.

The verb "to get" here doesn't have to do with acquiring something, [but causing a thing to be done on your behalf](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get) (see definition 9 under the transitive verb). As in "getting somebody to move" by nudging them, or "getting somebody to be quiet" by shushing them.

So you can read the passage this way:

> It seems like only yesterday when The Roman tried to hire an assassin to murder his nephew.